# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col 4 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, sqlite, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to get values from SQLite Database and adding them to an ArrayList. I don't know what the problem is. I can post more code if there is no problem in these code parts.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql ="create table tablo(id integer primary key,tipi text,turu text, miktar text, notlar text ) ";
    db.execSQL(sql);



 public List<String> listAll(){


    List<String>liste = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from tablo",null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        int id = c.getInt(0);
        String tipi=c.getString(1);
        String turu = c.getString(2);
        String miktar = c.getString(3);
        String notlar =c.getString(4);

        Data d = new Data(id,tipi,turu,miktar,notlar);
        String toSt =d.toString();
        liste.add(toSt);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A likely cause is that you have changed the SQL that creates the table by adding the **notlar** column.

However simply changing that line alone will not make the change as the database helper's `onCreate` method only runs when the database is created.

Additionally in the `listAll` method the line `c.moveToFirst();` is very likely not wanted, as it will skip the first row. Hence the message indicating the problem at row 1 instead of row 0.

To fix the issues,

1) Amend the code to remove `c.moveToFirst();`.

2) Do one of the following :-

- Delete the App's data.
- Uninstall the App.

3) Rerun the App.